# How to Logout from ALB OIDC Session?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, openid-connect, aws-application-load-balancer

I am using OIDC for authentication and login with ALB.
On successfully login I can see AWSELBAuthSessionCookie-0 in my browser.
For logout I am setting above cookie value to -1 and redirecting user to application home.
I am expecting it should redirect me to OIDC login page again but I an not getting login page again ALB cookie get created automatically and I can see home page without re login.

here is code in golang --

```
  deletingCookie := http.Cookie{Name: "AWSELBAuthSessionCookie-0", Path: "/", MaxAge: -1}
  http.SetCookie(w, &deletingCookie)
  http.Redirect(w, req, "https://www.test.com/", http.StatusFound)
```

Comment: did u find any solution for logout?

Comment: OIDC providers MUST provide an `end_session_endpoint` in the return value when calling the discovery url (typically `/.well-known/openid-configuration`). See https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-rpinitiated-1_0.html#OPMetadata for details.

Answer (score 0):

The cookie option `maxage` if specified is a positive integer denoting the maximum age in seconds, and the `expires` option is a datetime object or UNIX timestamp.

And usually the cookie will be available at the root path `/` itself as given, and could be set to an empty value on trying to delete (expire).

So combining all the above, please try with:

```
deletingCookie := http.Cookie{Name: "AWSELBAuthSessionCookie-0", Value:"", Path: "/", MaxAge: 0}
http.SetCookie(w, &deletingCookie)
```

Comment: -1 should have the same effect as 0 here, from the source:
"MaxAge<0 means delete cookie now, equivalently 'Max-Age: 0'"